# validated_data is empty when making POST request with Django REST

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a new entry in my database with Django REST framework and I am able to successfully send a request however `validated_data` is empty:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, get_list_or_404
from .models import GetPurchases, CarFax
from .serializers import PurchasesSerializer
from .serializers import CarFaxSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response

# Create your views here.


class GetCarFax(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ''' This view will be used for POSTing new carfax reports to the database '''

    queryset = CarFax.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarFaxSerializer
    # authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []
    #print('TEST')

    def list(self, request):

        # accessed at url: ^api/v1/carfax/$
        queryset = CarFax.objects.all()
        serializer = CarFaxSerializer(queryset, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
        # accessed at url: ^api/v1/retrieve/{pk}/$
        queryset = CarFax.objects.all()
        record = get_list_or_404(queryset, vin__exact=pk)
        serializer = CarFaxSerializer(record, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def create(self, request, **validated_data):
        print('TEST')
        print(request.data)
        print(validated_data)
        serializer = CarFaxSerializer(CarFax.objects.create(**validated_data))
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        print(serializer.data)

        print(headers)
        return Response(serializer.data, headers=headers)
```

serializers.py

```
class CarFaxSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CarFax
        fields = ('vin', 'structural_damage', 'total_loss',
                  'accident', 'airbags', 'odometer', 'recalls',
                  'last_updated')
```

When I print `request.data` I can see the data I sent. However `validated_data` is empty, which is the dict I'm using to create the models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your ***`GetCarFax`*** class seems like messy :( because you'd override most of the methods, but it doesn't provide any advantages to the view. So change your **`GetCarFax`** view class to below,

```
class GetCarFax(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This view will be used for POSTing new carfax reports to the database
    """
    queryset = CarFax.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarFaxSerializer
    # authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []
    lookup_field = 'myfieldname'
```

This few lines of code will handle all the ***CRUD*** operations for you :)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I can't just use the default methods because for example I want to retrieve an object by a field name, rather than it's pk. Also I get 400 error when I try to POST to my API via a cURL request.

Comment: change your `lookup_field` in that particular case...(updated the answer)

Comment: I'll give that a try, did not consider that attribute at all.

Comment: Can you explain about those 3 methods? I mean what trying to do with those methods? , In your context

Comment: I want to list all the Carfax objects that have been created. Retrieve a certain one by the VIN of the car, and I want to create one. Nothing crazy

Comment: And like I said before if I use the default create() method I receive a 400 error

Comment: It's just a `400: bad request` error, I can't get anything else.

Comment: Okay so I got it working, in my headers I was using the `Content-Type` from the cURL request I got from the browser. I changed it to `application/json` and it works. I also put the create method in my serializer class

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is a nice refactoring but it doesn't answer the question, and thus may not help future readers (like myself, who just went through this).  The real reason validated data was empty was because the when you override `.create` on the `ModelViewSet` you wipe out the serializer model field bindings and have to explicitly specify them as you would on a regular serializer.

CarFax serializer should have been defined like so:

```
class CarFaxSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    vin = serializers.CharField(23),
    structural_damage = serializers.BooleanField(),
    total_loss = serializers.BooleanField(),
    accident = serializers.BooleanField(),
    airbags = serializers.BooleanField(),
    odometer = serializers.IntegerField(),
    recalls = serialziers.BooleanField(),
    last_updated = serializers.DateField(),

    class Meta:
        model = CarFax
        fields = ('vin', 'structural_damage', 'total_loss',
                  'accident', 'airbags', 'odometer', 'recalls',
                  'last_updated')
```

Comment: Thanks for this informative reply, but I'm a bit confused. I thought I was merely inheriting the modelSerializer class, didn't realize I was overriding it

Comment: You overrode the `create` method.  Any time you use inheritance and define a method that is defined in the parent you override it.

Comment: Oh, I see I made a mistake in my answer.  I meant you overrode `.create` on the `ModelViewSet`.  Sorry I was solving the same issue yesterday.  Apparently my head was spinning as I wrote this.  Solution is still the same though, you have to explicitly define the model fields.  I suppose you could mess with calling super() in your `ModelViewSet` but I think there was some issue I was looking at on the GitHub for Django rest framework that recommended this method.

Comment: Ah I see, make sense. Thank you I'll keep this in mind for the future!